# iOS UIInterfaceOrientation not working with iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiinterfaceorientation, ios5

when i    use the `UIInterfaceOrientation` at any device of iOS 4 its work perfect
but when use it in iOS 5 its not like iOS 4

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
   return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || 
   interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

any idea

Comment: It works fine for me. Can you elaborate on how it's "not working"?

Comment: on the iPhone iOS 5 just the status bar rotate but the screen of the app don't

Comment: what kind of subviews do you have in the view controller ? have you  changed any resizing masks programmatically or from IB ?

Comment: Make sure in the "Target"->"Summary" you allow for the app to support more than one orientation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you send:

```
 [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications]
```

in your app delegate? If not match it with and "end..." message - google these methods for more information